# Python keeps having new versions (in its name). Do other languages have this?

Tags: python

Conceptually it makes sense, as the language is improved/ evolves, but I have never heard of Java 2, C++ v2 having 2, or 3 or 4, etc *in their name*.
I know there are different (continuously newer types of JS. But it is not reflected in it's name the way it is in Python). Should this not be standardized across languages? 
Will there be a Python 4? Probably. Will it/ should it be called Python 4? Or just called Python? 
Or, should it be called something completely different (like with JS - *ES6*)

Comment: c++ has c++98, c++03, c++11, c++14, and c++17

Comment: Java also gives us new versions. recently 7, 8, and 9

Comment: "but I have never heard of Java, C++ having 2, or 3" They do, you just happen to not have heard much.

Comment: Yes they do. The python 2 to python 3 was a little more painful than most due to quite a bit of broken backwards compatibility. This is why the python 2/3 difference is a little more infamous than for other languages.

Comment: Who knows besides the BDFL?

Comment: What do you mean by "in its name"? There is only Python with different versions. The aliases `python3`, `python3.6`, `python2.7` are just for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

Both C++ and Java have undergone many changes over the years.

- See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) for the Java version history (for ex. Java SE 6, 7, 8).
- See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) under Standardization for C++ changes (for ex. C++98, C++03, C++11, etc.).

It is natural for any language (including Python) to undergo extensions and upgrades.

Comment: The version changes are not reflected in the name though, like with Python. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: You could say the same for Python. I can say, "My language of choice is Python". Then somebody might ask, which version of Python? Same goes with C++ and Java. One important point might be that some aspects of Python3 are not backwards compatible with Python2. So in that sense it's important to clearly state which version of Python you're talking about, since many people still use Python2 but support for Python2 will end in 2020.